# Can deployment diagrams have components in UML?

Tags: uml

I have these two questions:

Can deployment diagrams have components in UML?

Can component diagrams have nodes in UML?

I've seen many diagrams mixing diagrams elements and is making me confused.

Comment: You can do anything you want with a diagram.  What are you actually asking?

Comment: I am worried about the standar for specific diagrams. Ex.: if is a deployment diagram, it is ok to use component or even mix the two diagrams type in one?

Comment: Something like this?  http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/deploymentDiagram.htm

Comment: That is exactly what Im talking about. There should be artifacts, not component.

Comment: Related: [In UML, can a component be placed inside a node?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/308413/52522)

Answer (score 1):

> UML specification does not preclude mixing of different kinds of
>   diagrams, e.g. to combine structural and behavioral elements to show a
>   state machine nested inside a use case. Consequently, the boundaries
>   between the various kinds of diagrams are not strictly enforced. At
>   the same time, some UML Tools do restrict set of available graphical
>   elements which could be used when working on specific type of diagram.

https://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html

So, Answering your questions:

Yes, deployment diagrams can have components in UML and

Yes, component diagrams can have nodes in UML.

It's not against of UML specification.

From my experience combining deployment diagram and component diagram can be very descriptive for visualizing application architecture.